# phpstorm ставит двоеточие в stylus

Tags: phpstorm, emmet, stylus

phpStorm в stylus ставит двоеточие, в настройках Emmet или плагине Stylus подобных настроек не нашел. Подскажите как их отключить?

[image: phpstorm stylus]

Comment: это настройки самого редактора, а не эммета. 

Settings -> Code Style -> General -> Tabs and Indents

    Indent – отступ
    Continuation indent – отступ, если следующая строка продолжает предыдущую строку

Comment: там нет ничего связанного с двоеточием, только настройки размера отступов. Причем примеры стилей на привью, нарисованы без двоеточия.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, никак :( Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за [WEB-15575](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15575)